# Which type of mortar/cement should be used for rock wall?

Tags: masonry

What kind of cement or mortar should be used to repair this broken rock wall? The right side is still together but the left side has cracked apart over the years. I'm in Georgia in spring, if that makes a difference.

[image: wall]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the rock walls I seen built, a very coarse sand is used, mixed with portland cement, the mix proportions I do not remember, but it should be something like 1 cement, 5 sand, maybe.... mixed with a little water to make "dry pack", like what is used in shower bases. There is also a slurry made of portland and water, to the consistency of paint. This is painted on the setting surface of the stone before it is laid to act as a bonder to the dry pack. The coarse sand used, helps support the stone better. It doesn't allow the stone to settle so much.

The slurry will settle, and will need to be stirred to keep in in solution. I have also seen the slurry poured onto the dry pack along with the painting of the stone with it.